# Excel style conditional numeric formats in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, number-formatting

I need to use Excel conditional format strings to format numbers in a .Net application. For those unfamiliar with them, the Excel format strings look like this:

```
[>=2]#,##0.0;[<=-2]-#,##0.0;#,##0.00
```

...which should be interpreted as "use the first format for numbers greater than two, the second for numbers lower than -2 and the third format for everything else".

Before I go ahead and build my own custom format string parser, does anyone know if there is anything similar to this in .Net that I could use? I'm aware there's the ;-separator for format strings, but it doesn't seem be able to take conditions beyond "is negative/positive/zero" into account as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to implement the formatting yourself but you can hook into .NET's existing formatting framework by using the interfaces [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) and [`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx).

Here is one example on how to do that. A `ConditionalFormatter` class is created that consists of several `ConditionalFormat` objects. The `ConditionalFormat` class has a `Predicate` and a `Format`. The `ConditionalFormatter` will search all `ConditionalFormat` objects in sequence finding the first where `Predicate` is true and use the associated `Format`. The formatter uses the letter 'Z' as the format string.

```
class ConditionalFormat<T> where T : IFormattable {
  public Func<T, Boolean> Predicate { get; set; }
  public String Format { get; set; }
  public static readonly Func<T, Boolean> Tautology = _ => true;
}

class ConditionalFormatter<T> : Collection<ConditionalFormat<T>>, IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
  where T : IFormattable {

  public const String FormatString = "Z";

  readonly CultureInfo cultureInfo;

  public ConditionalFormatter(IEnumerable<ConditionalFormat<T>> conditionalFormats)
    : this(conditionalFormats, null) { }

  public ConditionalFormatter(IEnumerable<ConditionalFormat<T>> conditionalFormats, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    : base(conditionalFormats.ToList()) {
    this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
  }

  public Object GetFormat(Type formatType) {
    return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
  }

  public String Format(String format, Object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
    if (arg.GetType() != typeof(T))
      return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
    var formatUpperCase = format.ToUpperInvariant();
    if (formatUpperCase != FormatString)
      return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);

    var value = (T) arg;
    foreach (var conditionalFormat in this)
      if (conditionalFormat.Predicate(value))
        return ((IFormattable) value).ToString(conditionalFormat.Format, cultureInfo);

    throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("No format matching value {0}.", value));
  }

  String HandleOtherFormats(String format, Object arg) {
    var formattable = arg as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null)
      return formattable.ToString(format, this.cultureInfo);
    else if (arg != null)
      return arg.ToString();
    else
      return String.Empty;
  }

}
```

The class is generic and you will have to create an instance that matches the type you want to format. Here is an example using `Double`:

```
var conditionalFormatter = new ConditionalFormatter<Double>(
  new[] {
    new ConditionalFormat<Double> {
      Predicate = d => -2 < d && d < 2,
      Format = "#,##0.00"
    },
    new ConditionalFormat<Double> {
      Predicate = ConditionalFormat<Double>.Tautology,
      Format = "#,##0.0"
    },
  }
);
var value = 1234.5678;
var formattedValue = String.Format(conditionalFormatter, "Value is {0:Z}", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting solution: there is a library called [SmartFormat](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat/wiki) that includes a conditional formatter.

The syntax for your example would be:

```
var output = Smart.Format("{0:>=2?{0:#,##0.0}|<=-2?{0:-#,##0.0}|{0:#,##0.00}}", value);
```

For an explanation of the syntax, see [ConditionalFormatter](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat/wiki/Conditional-Formatting-Syntax).

However, if you wanted to support the exact Excel syntax you mentioned above, you could download the `SmartFormat` source and modify the `ConditionalFormatter` to support your syntax.  It uses a Regex to parse each `(condition)`, so that would be easy to modify.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write if/else if statements. There is no direct way

```
string numberToFormat = //state your number here
string FormattedString = null;

if(numberToFormat >2)
{
    //Format 1
    //e.g. FormattedString = String.Format("{0:0.00}", numberToFormat);

}

else if(numberToFormat < -2)
{
     //Format 2
}

else 
{
     // Format Default     
}
```

This is the shortest way. But of course  you can get your own conditional formatter.